# Am I using `man` argument to APA6 package correctly?

Tags: apa-style, apa6

Creating a short paper in APA format, I loaded `apa6` package and after compiling the first draft wuth `Lorem Ipsum` I realized that it did not use double spacing. The manual seems to state that `man` argument would force double spacing. But it only threw an error. Removed `lipsum` just to be sure, still the same thing:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,man]{apa6}

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

The error I am getting:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@shorttitle 

l.5 \end{document}
```

Weirdly enough, the result renders, but I do get an error. Very confusing.

Comment: I've edited here to include the exact message: you seem to need a short title!

Comment: Apparently you ran it on command line, and I was running in TexStudio, which was throwing a misleading error message. APA6 manual, page 3 etc did not seem to state that the short title was mandatory, but it is in `man` mode where it wants to build a page header from it.

Answer (score 1):

You should include `\shorttitle{}` empty, even if you don't wanna use it. I was having the same trouble with the `apa7` style package. This little workaround fixed it.